# List Network Adapter name with IPv4 address

Tags: vb.net, networking, ipv4

Im trying to list the only ACTIVE network adapter with its IPv4 addresses on one computer. i have this code but it will list every network card either its connected or not.

```
  Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    ListView1.View = View.Details
    ListView1.GridLines = True
    ListView1.FullRowSelect = True
    ListView1.Columns.Add("Interface Name", 100)
    ListView1.Columns.Add("MAC address", 100)
    ListView1.Columns.Add("IPv4 address", 100)
    ListView1.Columns.Add("Network Mask", 100)
    ListView1.Columns.Add("IPv6 Address", 100)
    ListView1.Columns.Add("Link Local Address", 100)
    ListView1.Columns.Add("IPv5 Address", 100)
End Sub

Private Sub getinterface()
    'get all network interface available in system
    Dim nics As NetworkInterface() = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()
    If nics.Length < 0 Or nics Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox("No network interfaces found")
        Exit Sub
    End If


    'if interfaces are found let list them. first clear the listview items
    ListView1.Items.Clear()


    For Each netadapter As NetworkInterface In nics
        'next lets set variable to get interface properties for later use
        Dim intproperties As IPInterfaceProperties = netadapter.GetIPProperties()
        'now add the network adaptername to the list
        ListView1.Items.Add(netadapter.Name)


        'now get the mac address of this interface
        Dim paddress As PhysicalAddress = netadapter.GetPhysicalAddress()
        Dim addbyte As Byte() = paddress.GetAddressBytes()
        Dim macaddress As String = ""


        'now loop through the bytes value and change it to hex
        For i = 0 To addbyte.Length - 1
            macaddress &= addbyte(i).ToString("X2") 'change string to hex
            'now let separate hex value with -except last one
            If i <> addbyte.Length - 1 Then
                macaddress &= "-"
            End If

        Next

        'ount item in listview
        Dim icount As Integer = ListView1.Items.Count

        'use try
        Try
            With ListView1.Items(icount - 1).SubItems
                .Add(macaddress)
                '.Add(intproperties.UnicastAddresses(2).Address.ToString)
                .Add(intproperties.AnycastAddresses(2).Address.ToString)

                .Add(intproperties.UnicastAddresses(2).IPv4Mask.ToString)

                .Add(intproperties.UnicastAddresses(0).Address.ToString)
                .Add(intproperties.UnicastAddresses(1).Address.ToString)
                '.Add( IPAddress.Parse(a).AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork )
            End With

        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try

    Next
    'now lets make auto size columns
    ListView1.AutoResizeColumns(ColumnHeaderAutoResizeStyle.ColumnContent)
End Sub
```

Is there a better way to do this? list the only connected network adapter with IPv4 address. i already try WMI code editor but not sure which one to take for generate adapter name and IP address

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the solution I found.

```
For Each netadapter As NetworkInterface In nics
        'next lets set variable to get interface properties for later use
        Dim intproperties As IPInterfaceProperties = netadapter.GetIPProperties()

        'get first number of IP address.
        Dim firstnum As String
        Try
            firstnum = intproperties.UnicastAddresses(1).Address.ToString()
            firstnum = firstnum.Substring(0, firstnum.IndexOf("."))
        Catch ex As Exception
            'If not IPv4 then
            firstnum = "NOPE"
        End Try

        'check if first number if valid IPv4 address
        If Val(firstnum) > 0 And Not Val(firstnum) = 169 And Not Val(firstnum) = 127 Then


            'now add the network adaptername to the list
            ListView1.Items.Add(netadapter.Name)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use netadapter.OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Up to select the adapters that are active.

(Sorry, that's C#, but the equivalent in VB should be easy.)